# Can <condPageBreak height='?cm'> change dynamically?

Tags: odoo, rml

I have a `<blockTable>` that change size depending an user input.
I want to continue drawing on next page if there is no sufficient space to draw the blocktable on the same page.

```
<condPageBreak height='1in'/>
<blocklTable ...>
    ...
```

How can I change  `blockTable height` to jump to the next page if there is not enough space on the current page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about dynamically change or break page. But I use below method. May be it will useful to you.

Try with this RML reports.

The `<condPageBreak/>` tag is a "CONDitional Page Break". To use it, you give it a height in any units that RML can handle.

It then compares this height with the remaining available space on a page. If the space is sufficient, then the next elements are placed on the current page, but if there is less space than the height you have given it anything following the `<condPageBreak/>` is continued on the next page

`<condPageBreak/>` has only one attribute - the mandatory one of 
*height*

**For Example:**

```
<condPageBreak height="1in"/>
<condPageBreak height="72"/>
```

For more details: [RML User Guide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf)

**NOTE:**

Use above examples before the start of `<blockTable>` tag

For Example:

```
<condPageBreak height="1in"/>
    <blockTable style="Table4">
    .
    .
    .
    </blockTable>
```

Comment: That's why I was write on first line of my answer. :-) I'm also in interested to know about it.